# Getting 401 from ajax using an application password

Tags: rest-api, authentication

Got the following code running on a local wordpress install. I have created an application password for the admin user but am still getting a 401 unauthorised. What am i missing?

Here's the code

```
jQuery.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    url: 'http://the-lead-magnet-company.local/wp-json/wp/v2/posts',
                    data: JSON.stringify({  
                    title: me.title(),
                    content: 'Here is some content',
                    status: 'published'
                    }),
                    beforeSend: function ( xhr ) {
                        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic admin:DqfX r0YT hQE5 lsgu 2Y7d PJv5');
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert("posted");
                    },
                    error: function (error) {
                        alert("FAILD:" + error);
                    }
                });
```

Comment: You need to invalidate that application password, it is no longer secure. Btw where is this code running? If this code is running on a page served by `the-lead-magnet-company.local` then the use of basic authentication is unnecessary and inappropriate

Comment: It’s local. It ain’t going anywhere near a live system

Comment: Can I ask, why are you using HTTP basic auth for authentication? You only need this is you're interacting with a remote REST API or from an application/CLI

Comment: I’m trying to follow the docs for doing a post Ajax call. I’m guessing from your response I don’t need it.

Comment: Without it I still get a 401

Comment: you need a valid nonce + standard login cookie, the REST API handbook covers how to do this. The basic authentication header you are trying to use here is unnecessary, and not a good path to go down, you should abandon it in favor of a more normal approach to things

Comment: There are code examples here on how to create and use the nonce when making the request https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/#cookie-authentication complete with an example that creates a post titled "Hello Moon" via `POST`

Answer (score 1):

You should use cookie based authentication instead of basic auth. Delete the basic auth/application password authentication code.

Follow the cookie authentication example that creates a post via the REST API from the REST API handbook:

https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/#cookie-authentication

1. Create a valid nonce for use in your AJAX requests  in PHP `wp_create_nonce( 'wp_rest' )` as the docs tell you to
2. Add a `beforeSend` to your AJAX call like the docs suggest that adds the nonce in a HTTP header:

```js
    beforeSend: function ( xhr ) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader( 'X-WP-Nonce', your_nonce_variable );
    },
```

3. Make the request while logged into the site from the same domain

Comment: So there is no way to achieve this without editing PHP code? I was specifically hoping to avoid this.

Comment: That doc also has a section at the end that might explain why your current code fails to work, eitherway there's no reason here to use application passwords, it's not a secure usage and doesn't make a lot of sense

Comment: You need an appropriate nonce value, you cannot avoid making PHP changes to enable this. Your only hope is that another part of your site followed these steps and you can reuse their nonce value

Comment: Also keep in mind you did not mention the no-PHP requirement, I can only answer the literal question you asked

Comment: I did on the previous post but that was closed down. Thanks for the help. I’ll try and work out what needs editing. I would have expected this to be a setting in Wordpress. Seems odd that it’s not.

Comment: It's highly unlikely to ever be a setting in WP as this is coding and it's _highly unusual_ to be writing javascript on the frontend when you do not have access to the backend. Also this nonce changes over time. This is why application passwords exist, and why application passwords have a UI, because users who are not you who are running code that is not on your site will need credentials for remote access. What you are trying to do is not remote though, and I'd still ***strongly*** recommend that you read the document I linked you to in full, especially the last part that I referenced